# How to set up a Git hook so that after pushing to ssh://peter@foo.com/~/bar.com.git, it will go to ~/bar.com and do a git pull?

Tags: git, githooks

I was advised to set up on a remote server

```
foo.com/~/bar.com       # live webpage content
foo.com/~/bar.com.git   # a bare repo
```

so, from my local machine, I can do a

```
git push
```

and it will push to `foo.com/~/bar.com.git` on the remote machine  (the full path is `ssh://peter@www.foo.com/~/bar.com.git`

How can a **hook** be added, so that after the push, the remote server will `cd ~/bar.com` and do a `git pull` so that all content is updated (the same as the local machine)?  (no need to run `git update` like for Mercurial?)

(this is related to [Cannot git clone a folder on a server and then edit and git push?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5703324/cannot-git-clone-a-folder-on-a-server-and-then-edit-and-git-push)  right now I can ssh to `foo.com` and `cd ~/bar.com` and wait there and do a `git pull` whenever after a `git push` from the local machine, but it'd be nice to have it done automatically)

**Update**: please only post an answer if you know specific details and how to do it.  If you google and post the first or second google result here, it is not going to help.

**Update 2**: I went to `~/bar.com.git/hooks` and add a new file `post-receive` with the content:

```
#!/bin/bash

cd ~/bar.com
git pull ../bar.com.git master
```

and also `chmod 755 post-receive`, and if I edit a file on the local machine, and then `git com -m "ok"` and `git push`, it doesn't make the change go into the remote machine's folder `~/bar.com`

Answer (score 55, accepted):

You can add a [`post-receive`](http://git-scm.com/docs/githooks#post-receive) hook to the `~/bar.com.git` repo for this. To do this add to the `~/bar.com.git/hooks/` directory an executable file `post-receive` with the content:

```
#!/bin/sh

unset $(git rev-parse --local-env-vars)
cd ~/bar.com
git pull
```

**Make sure** the `post-receive` file has the executable bits(e.g. 755).

Now whenever something is pushed to the `~/bar.com.git` repo, the `~/bar.com` repo is updated automatically.

See also

- [getting "fatal: not a git repository: '.'" when using post-update hook to execute 'git pull' on another repo](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4043609/460387)
- [Git - post-receive hook with git pull “Failed to find a valid git directory”](https://serverfault.com/q/107608)

to understand why unsetting some environment variables is necessary.

Comment: I think I know something like this, but how?  what are the details?  you may as well say go buy the Git book and the answer is there

Comment: `post-receive` is simply a shell script. You can put anything in there.

Comment: @動靜能量 Try it again with the Git's environment variables unset.

Comment: Thanks you!!! That unset thing there saved my day :-D I can breathe again... Ah...

Comment: +1 exactly what I needed, when I needed it, praise to the hivemind :)

Comment: It doesnt work for me, while I've done exactly what you told to... ANYONE HELP :)

Answer (score 1):

I use the following `post-update` script (make sure you set executable bit on it):

```
#!/bin/sh
rm -rf ~/public_html/xxx
git-archive --format=tar --prefix=xxx master | tar x -C ~/public_html
```

It does the thing, but there's a short window when the site is not available. Doing `git pull` directly in yours `~/bar.com` will expose git's `.git` directory, so make sure you either block it in your http server, or keep `.git` somewhere higher in directory hierarchy, ie. something like:

```
~
 \
  - repo
    \
     - .git
     - bar.com
       \
        - your content
```

Comment: you remove the whole directory and re-populate it?  What if the directory is 300MB and all you did was a 1 line change?  redo the whole 300MB?

Comment: It works for me (my site is quite small). In your case the `git pull` approach would surely be better. Also note: there's no sense to have one repo to which you push to and another one right next to it that would pull from the first one. It seems more sensible to just push to one repo and have it update its contents automatically (git used to work that way, but they have changed that. IIRC there's some option to revert back to the behavior you'd desire.).

Comment: You could also checkout the archive into a temp location and rsync it with the "working" directory.