# How to keep two git repos synchronized?

Tags: git, github, bitbucket

I'm running my own private git repository on a private server in a colo facility. I use it for any private projects that I cannot open source. I use github for all of my open source work.

I do development on a desktop ubuntu machine and on my MacBookPro. As I make changes on my development systems, I push the changes to the origin in the colo and pull to the other system. I'm pretty good about keeping all three systems up-to-date for the most part, mostly for backup and disaster recovery purposes.

Now that BitBucket is offering private git hosting for free, I'm considering adding a clone of my projects there. Besides, then I could use the extra features provided by BitBucket that my barebones private git server doesn't provide. However, I'd like to continue to keep a copy of the private repos on my colo server as well for backup redundancy.

So I have a few questions:

1. Without changing my standard development process (edit, add, commit, push), how can I automatically sync commits pushed to my server to a bitbucket project? Any time I push to my git server, I'd like those commits to automatically get pushed to my bitbucket project. I don't want to change my workflow and would like as little changes necessary to my development clients.
2. If I want to use bitbucket as my primary git repo, how do I migrate my projects from my private git server to bitbucket?
3. Once I migrate to bitbucket, I'd still like another backup on my server. How can I automatically have commits to bitbucket get pushed to my git server? This is basically the reverse of question 1.

Answer (score 7):

For #1, the easiest solution is using a hook on your remote repo that automatically pushes to BitBucket.

For #2: You simply add bitbucket as a remote and push to it instead of origin. If you have any tracking branches (check `.git/config`), change `remote = origin` to whatever name you used for bitbucket. Another solution would be removing/renaming your existing `origin` remote and adding bitbucket as origin.

For #3: A cronjob executing `git fetch` is probably the easiest way to do this.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give your suggestions a try!

Comment: @Tauren - any feedback on this issue?

Comment: #1: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5769568/how-to-set-up-a-git-hook-so-that-after-pushing-to-ssh-peterfoo-com-bar-com

Answer (score 4):

Maybe you could add a git hook to your private server to push automatically to bitbucket.

In the pro git book, there is a chapter about git hooks: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks

Comment: Thanks for the link, it looks like it will help.