# Git pull until there is something to pull

Tags: git, wait, pull

Is there a way to *git pull* until there is something to pull.

Say i'm waiting for a collegue to push his latest changes, since i'm impatient and not looking at his screen, i just run **watch git pull** until i see something has been pulled, but i could miss the moment and waste a little more time than necessary. (note: yes, this is a very minor inconvenience, but an inconvenience still :) )

*git pull* does not seem to have a different return value whether it has actually pulled something, but maybe there's some obscure, undocumented option that i don't know about?

**EDIT:**
Thanks for the answers, i added this to my .zshrc:

```
alias gitpullwait="git pull | grep "Already up-to-date" > /dev/null; while [ $? -ne 1 ]; do git pull | grep "Already up-to-date" > /dev/null; done; notify-send Pull f$
```

It looks ugly but it works for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pipe git output to awk/grep to look for the message that would have been printed if there's a non empty pull, and then use notify-send to flash a notification message on your desktop.

Also I'd recommend not doing git pull with the script, instead do a git fetch with the script and then merge manually so you don't get unexpected merging issues.

Comment: This the simplest answer, i like it, i'll edit my question with what i did.

Answer (score 1):

The usual way is to have a local listener which will detect a [webhook](https://developer.github.com/webhooks/) (set on the server side).
That webhook would send a [JSON payload](https://developer.github.com/webhooks/#payloads) that the local listener can interpret and act upon.

The link I mention is for a GitHub repo, BitBucket has its own version ([POST hook](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/POST+hook+management)).

For a private server, you would setup a post-receive hook to push to your workstation a JSON message signaling the latest push.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways to go about this, depending on your situation:

1. Configure a git hook on your friend's machine to SSH into yours and execute a git pull upon completion of push - not recommended but an option. http://git-scm.com/book/en/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks
2. Configure a git hook on the git server 'post-receive' to SSH into your machine and execute a git pull - recommended if you can actually set git hooks on your git server. [How to set up a Git hook so that after pushing to ssh://peter@foo.com/~/bar.com.git, it will go to ~/bar.com and do a git pull?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5769568/how-to-set-up-a-git-hook-so-that-after-pushing-to-ssh-peterfoo-com-bar-com)
3. Write a cron job to execute git pull on your machine every set interval - the not-very-performance-minded but fast approach to solving this issue. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CronHowto

I would recommend option #2 if you have access to the remote repos server. Just remember, that unless you want this behaviour to happen **always** you will need to delete the hook afterwards.