# What is a good Git strategy for maintaining source code on www.hostingcompany.com/~/mysite.com?

Tags: git

This is related to [Cannot git clone a folder on a server and then edit and git push?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5703324/cannot-git-clone-a-folder-on-a-server-and-then-edit-and-git-push)

So let's say the hosting company is   `www.hostingcompany.com`

and when I ssh to it, I am in `~` and I will see

```
~/mysite.com
~/any_other_folders
```

What is a good Git workflow to version control all source code in `~/mysite.com`, and able to `git clone` to my local PC?  And so that I can make modification locally, and then issue one line and push to the repo and have all code on `~/mysite.com` up to date?

Is using a git repo, and then `sftp` from local PC to `~/mysite.com` a good way?  I prefer not to do that as it is harder to see if everything is sync'ed.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cannot git clone a folder on a server and then edit and git push?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5703324/cannot-git-clone-a-folder-on-a-server-and-then-edit-and-git-push)

Answer (score 2):

Copying the answer straight from the [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5703324/cannot-git-clone-a-folder-on-a-server-and-then-edit-and-git-push) where you already got it:

You have two options:

1. Make a bare repository (`mysite.com.git`) and a non-bare repository (`mysite.com`). In the bare repository, add a `post-update` hook to `git --git-dir=.../mysite.com pull`

   Note, that you may want to create the non-bare repository by cloning from the bare one with `-s` flag or set up `.git/objects/info/alternates` afterwards to avoid copying all the data.
2. Make just one repository and:

   1. Detach the head: `git checkout master@{0}`
   2. Add a `post-update` hook to `git merge master`

   The reason here is that git refuses to modify the checked-out branch, but if you uncheckout the branch, you will be able to push. And you will be able to update the working directory from a hook (hook is a script placed in `hooks` directory in the repository). You can either create a separate branch and check out that, or you can use the "detached HEAD" state (as suggested above—git remembers which branch is checked out by having a special reference "HEAD" that points to the branch, but if you check out something, that is not a branch, it is made to point to a revision directly and that's called a "detached branch" and since no branch is checked out, allows you to push to any of them).
3. Make just one repository and:

   1. Turn off the push-to-checked-out-branch check.
   2. Add a `post-update` hook to `git reset --hard` to re-checkout the branch when pushed.

   This option is only valid for read-only access, because the hook will discard any local changes each time you push.

If it's just check out and have it accessed read-only, the second option is slightly more efficient, but if you run some other commands on the working directory, the first is safer (you can wipe and re-create the working copy without worrying about the main repo). See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5219975/git-remote-for-testing).

**Edit:** added third option.

Comment: is `mysite.com.git` a directory or a file?  Do we create it using `mkdir mysite.com.git`, `cd mysite.com.git`, `git init --bare`, `cd ../mysite.com`, and then `git init`, `git add .`, `git commit -m "ok"`, `git push ../mysite.com.git master` ?

Comment: First option is the best, in my opinion

Comment: @動靜能量: `mysite.com.git` is a bare repository, so a directory. Yes, you create it as you say. It is a common convention to name bare repositories with `.git` suffix.