# Git Post-Receive Hook for Pushing from One Server to Another

Tags: git, workflow

I have a development server and a production server. All developers push updates to the development server and the development server pushes updates to the production server.

Is there a Post-Receive hook for doing this? Assume that the development server and production server names are `dev1` and `prod1`.

If possible, is there a post-receive hook that checks for the tag `stable` before pushing to prod1?

Edit:
[image: Workflow example]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at my answer here:

[Git Automatically push to Dev and Production from Central Repository depending on branch pushed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5753346/git-automatically-push-to-dev-and-production-from-central-repository-depending-on/5754184#5754184)

Answer (score 0):

You can do whatever you like in the hook. Push --tags and specify the one you want.