# Cannot find my project files on the server gitolite is running

Tags: gitolite

I cannot find my project files on the server gitolite is running.
Basically, I built a git server using gitolite on a CentOS 6.2, and I created a new repository,I can successfully clone, pull, commit and push files to this new project, but when I logged in this server, trying to find my project files on it, I could not find them. the repository is in /home/mygituser/repositories/myproject.git/ , but none of my pushed files can be found any in there.

Is gitolite keeping the actual project contents somewhere else or is there a way to config and seperate project contents and its repository?

This is driving me crazy, any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gitolite operates with **bare** repositories.
A bare repo has no working tree, meaning no files.

That is why, by the way, your repo root directory ends with `.git`: it is a naming convention to reference bare repos.

See "[Git push only for bare repositories?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2147741/6309)" for more.

Your repos are managed by default on:

```
~git/repositories/myrepo1.git
~git/repositories/myrepo2.git
```

Generally, you don't need to look to the content of a repo while being on the server: you simply clone it on a client and look it there. (the clone won't be a bare repo by default)

You could clone it on the server, if you have a proper `~git/.ssh/id_rsa(.pub)` key declared as a user in the `gitolite.conf` file.
[It is what I do, as a test](https://github.com/VonC/compileEverything/blob/master/gitolite/install_or_update_gitolite.sh#L65-L67), after installing/updating gitolite on my server.
That works because of my local [ssh config file](https://github.com/VonC/compileEverything/blob/master/.ssh/config.tpl#L1-L5):

```
Host gitolitesrv
Hostname localhost
User @USERNAME@
Port @PORT_SSHD@
IdentityFile @H@/.ssh/gitoliteadm
```

So I have a `~git/.ssh/gitolite(.pub)` private and public key dedicated to gitolite admin, which I can use locally on the server to clone gitolite repo if I want.
That is because I use that [same key to setup gitolite](https://github.com/VonC/compileEverything/blob/master/gitolite/install_or_update_gitolite.sh#L37):

```
 GITOLITE_HTTP_HOME= gitolite setup -pk "${H}/.ssh/gitoliteadm.pub"
```

If you have a similar setup, you can then clone any repo on the server:

```
git clone gitolitesrv:gitolite-admin "${gtl}/ga"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your attention. can you please tell me where is the project content path by default? or there is no way to review them on gitolite server?

Comment: I found a related topic, and I think i am not gonna find a work copy on gitlite server as you guys suggested. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7060636/git-gitolite-moving-repos-after-setting-up-gitolite

Comment: @RossWang I have edited the answer (the `@variable@` are templates to be replace by real values)

Comment: Thank you very much! it is a great practice. I tried to review the project contents is for making sure all files were pushed correctly, this can be done by clone a new one.